# Error Importing Glib

Tags: python, python-3.x, importerror, glib, traceback

When trying to import glib in python 3 using `from gi.repository import glib`, I get an error saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2135, in _find_spec
AttributeError: 'DynamicImporter' object has no attribute 'find_spec'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/importer.py", line 53, in find_module
    'introspection typelib not found' % namespace)
ImportError: cannot import name glib, introspection typelib not found
```

I installed all the python glib/dev packages using apt-get on Ubuntu 14.04. Attempting to import the module in python 2 says the module doesn't exist.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: It throws an error as soon as it gets to the import statement. I've tried using the interactive interpreter, that's where it throws the error.

Comment: Interesting. Can I ask how you installed glib?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It works for me with `GLib` correctly capitalized:

```
from gi.repository import GLib
```

Comment: Well, that works. Odd, I've seen multiple websites spell it with different capitalization saying it works.

Comment: @Kookerus maybe you confused it with the old style `import glib`?

Comment: Maybe the site I copied it from had. I've seen `from gi.repository import glib` and `from gi.repository import Glib`

Comment: A quick Google search shows me lots of `from gi.repository import Glib` and `from gi.repository import GLib as glib`. Easy to confuse, anyway.